# Solve the differential equation $y=\frac{1}{D^2-1}x^2\cos x.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $y=\frac{1}{D^2-1}x^2\cos x.$

I solved the problem as:

Let $X=\cos x,Y=\sin x$ so, $X+iY=e^{ix}$
We proceed to calculate $\frac{1}{D^2-1}x^2e^{ix}.$

We have $$y_p=\frac{1}{D^2-1}x^2e^{ix}=e^{ix}\frac{1}{(D+i)^2-1}x^2=e^{ix}\frac{1}{D^2+2Di-2}x^2=-e^{ix}(\frac 12)(1+(-\frac{D^2+2Di}{2}))^{-1}x^2=-\frac{e^{ix}}{2}(1-\frac{D^2}{2}-Di+\frac{(D^2+2Di)^2}{(2)^2})x^2=-\frac{e^{ix}}{2}(1-\frac{D^2}{2}-Di-D^2)x^2=-\frac{e^{ix}}{2}(x^2-1-2xi-2)=-\frac 12(x^2-2xi-3)(\cos x+i\sin x).$$

We note that, $Re(y_p)=y=-\frac12(x^2-3)\cos x-\frac 12(-2xi)(i\sin x)=\frac 12(3-x^2)\cos x-x\sin x.$

But I am surprised to see that the answer given is $x\sin x+\frac 12\cos x(1-x^2).$ I could not find any mistake in my approach nor in my calculations. This means the only possible conclusion is the answer given, surely has a typo, is it ?

Next, the method I applied, is it a standard way? Is there a name for this method ?

Comment: You have lost a sign  somewhere. $(1+(-a))^{-1}=(1-a)^{-1}=1+a+a^2+...$

Comment: The answer given is correct  you have a sign mistake as pointed by Lutz Lehmann.

Comment: The differential equation has a two-parameter family of solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y_p=\dfrac {1}{D^2-1}x^2 \cos x$$
$$2y_p=\dfrac {1}{D-1}x^2 \cos x -\dfrac {1}{D+1}x^2 \cos x$$
$$2y_p=e^x\dfrac {1}{D}e^{-x}x^2 \cos x -e^{-x}\dfrac {1}{D}e^xx^2 \cos x$$
$$2y_p=e^x\int e^{-x}x^2 \cos xdx - e^{-x}\int e^xx^2 \cos xdx$$
$$y_p=\dfrac {f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$$
Where:
$$f(x)=e^x\int e^{-x}x^2 \cos xdx $$
The integral can be calculated by integration by parts:
$$2I=e^{-x}((x+1)^2\sin x -(x^2-1) \cos x)$$
$$2f(x)=(x+1)^2\sin x -(x^2-1) \cos x$$
Then
$$y_p=\dfrac {f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$$
The given answer is correct:
$$\boxed {2y_p=(1-x^2)\cos x +2x \sin x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution. Denote

$$x^2\cos x \equiv D_\lambda^2\left[-\cos\lambda x\right]_{\lambda = 1}$$

Note that $\cos \lambda x$ is an eigenvector of the operator $D_x^2$ with eigenvalue $-\lambda^2$. This gives us

$$\frac{1}{D_x^2-1}x^2\cos\lambda x = -\frac{D_\lambda^2}{D_x^2-1}\cos\lambda x = D_\lambda^2\left[\frac{\cos \lambda x}{\lambda^2+1}\right]$$

Evaluating the derivatives and plugging in gives us our final answer

$$\left[\frac{8\lambda^2\cos \lambda x}{(\lambda^2+1)^3}-\frac{2\cos\lambda x}{(\lambda^2+1)^2}+\frac{4\lambda x\sin \lambda x}{(\lambda^2+1)^2}-\frac{x^2 \cos \lambda x}{\lambda^2+1}\right]_{\lambda = 1} = \left(\frac{1-x^2}{2}\right)\cos x + x \sin x$$